# How to call function fron other python projects into anonther project stored in same directory?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have 10 different python projects stored in one folder (F:\Python_Code...). I want to call user define functions from 10 different projects into the last project (Say Project11) and by running Project11, all my 10 projects should run one by one.

I have tried multiple ways like os.path() and from project1 import function, etc. but no one work. I read about the change in PYTHONPATH, but I am still not able to do that. I am using PyCharm. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you add `F:\Python_Code` to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` ?

Comment: No. Actually I am not getting proper steps to add that. I have tried but not working

Answer (score 1):

soni smit!
Your solution wasn't that far away.
First you have to import the whole file with:

```
from . import filename
```

or just

```
import filename
```

if the file is in the same directory as your main file.
then you can call a function from that file with:

```
filename.functionname(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

I hope, it works for you!
~ostue

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to reference an upper-level directory for importing your packages.

If you're sure of what you're doing, you can change the working directory using **os.chdir(path_to_dir_that_can_access_all_your_modules)**.

If you need the flexibility to import your libs in a dynamic way, try using importlib.import_module('module_name').

ex.: 
        import os, importlib

```
    def import_module(base_path, module_path):
        try:
            backup_wd = os.getcwd() # backup original working directory
            os.chdir(base_path) # change directory
            return importlib.import_module(module_path) # import and return your module
        except:
            # Handle problems
            ...
        finally:
            os.chdir(backup) # go back to original directory in any case

    project10_module = import_module('F:\Python_Code', 'project10.utils.yourmodule')
    module_instance = project10_module(args)
```